# Pegar a cidade do usuario com IP

Tags: php, geolocalização

Estou precisando pegar a cidade que o usuário se encontra no momento do acesso ao Painel de Controle do Site.

### Porque eu preciso disso?

Estou querendo bloquear o acesso ao painel de controle somente para a cidade do meu cliente, quando ele não tiver *IP* fixo, caso ele tenha, eu bloqueio o acesso somente para o IP fixo dele.

Já testei pelo *GEOIP*, mas ele me da uma distancia muito grande, por exemplo:

Coloquei meu *IP* e ele me mostrou uma cidade a mais de 50 km de onde estou.

Alguém sabe como fazer isso?

Answer (score 3):

Você pode pegar informações usando XML seguinte:

http://www.geoplugin.net/xml.gp?ip=SEU_IP

Você coloca o IP no lugar `SEU_IP`

ou

http://www.ipinfodb.com/ip_location_api.php

Exemplo:

`http://api.ipinfodb.com/v3/ip-country/?key=<your_api_key>&ip=IP_AQUI`

Você coloca o IP no lugar `IP_AQUI` enquanto o `your_api_key` você coloca a sua chave, para ter isso, você tem que fazer o cadastro no site.

Comment: Vou dar uma olhada pra ver como funciona.. obrigado por enquanto

Comment: Eu dei uma ollhada e para fazer o cadastro diz que eu tenho que ter um "server IP", acredito que deva ser um ip fixo, coisa que eu não possuo, então acho que não vou conseguir fazer o cadastro e o teste :( me corrija se eu estiver errado, por favor.

Comment: Esse do geoplugin foi um dos que eu testei e me retornou uma cidade mais de 50 km de distancia de onde me encontro.. e o ipinfo, me retornou que estou em Porto Alegre.. que dá uns 40 km da minha cidade...

Comment: Desculpe, não tenho conhecimento o suficiente para coletar IP com muita precisão, não sei se é fácil achar um serviço desse. Recomendo um estudo melhor sobre isso, tenta no Google assim "ip location with precision", em inglês é melhor pois tem mais possibilidade de ter informações melhores. Se souber alguma coisa, compartilha aqui depois. =)
Boa sorte!

Answer (score 2):

Link: http://ip-api.com/json 
Documentação: http://ip-api.com/docs/api:json

Exemplo:

```
{
  "status": "success",
  "country": "United States",
  "countryCode": "US",
  "region": "CA",
  "regionName": "California",
  "city": "San Francisco",
  "zip": "94105",
  "lat": "37.7898",
  "lon": "-122.3942",
  "timezone": "America/Los_Angeles",
  "isp": "Wikimedia Foundation",
  "org": "Wikimedia Foundation",
  "as": "AS14907 Wikimedia US network",
  "query": "208.80.152.201"
}
```

Comment: Pra mim apareceu isso: 

{
"as":"AS8167 Brasil Telecom S/A - Filial Distrito Federal",
"city":"Sapiranga",
"country":"Brazil",
"countryCode":"BR",
"isp":"Oi Internet",
"lat":-29.6333,"lon":-51,
"org":"Oi Internet",
"query":"189.74.216.34",
"region":"RS",
"regionName":
"Rio Grande do Sul",
"status":"success",
"timezone":"America/Sao_Paulo",
"zip":""
}
Sapiranga fica a uns 25 km da minha cidade.. e eu preciso exato, acho que nao vou encontrar.. ja estou pensando em outra forma mas ainda não encontrei uma resposta melhor..

Comment: Acredito que depende muito também de fatores externos, como DNS, e os servidores das operadores. As vezes comigo no próprio Google mostra a cidade onde está o ISP, ou seja, uns 200Km longe, outras vezes aparece corretamente a cidade onde estou dependendo da rede.

Comment: Eu compreendo, mas para a finalidade que eu preciso não posso correr o risco do cliente estar na cidade e não poder acessar o Painel de Controle do Site porque na hora que ele foi logar apareceu que estava numa cidade a 30 km de onde se encontra :).. mas estou verificando a possibilidade de quando logar, enviar um email com um hash para autenticação, tipo um token, mas estou analisando ainda a possibilidade, mas obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: Interessante, de fato também não pensei nessa possibilidade, bloquear por região é complicado, ainda mais falando em cloud computing como é hoje em que pode ser acessado em qualquer lugar. Poderia ser feito algo como dois passos, como o Google utiliza. Já pensou sobre?